# Build jar and run spring boot from cmd

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-websocket, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm new to springboot and using springboot 2 version.

I would like to run my spring boot application using : **java -jar my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** from the command prompt.

However, when i build the application using eclipse it calls myService.getMyMethod() directly and does not build the jar.

I want to build the jar file first and then run **java -jar my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** from the command prompt which will invoke myService.getMyMethod()

I already have spring-boot-maven-plugin in pom.xml, running **mvn package** / **mvn install** starts the application but not generating the jar file in the target folder. mvn clean package also not working, MyApplication  is using implements CommandLineRunner and starts invoking the method on build, hence not generating the build jar file

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

private static String URL = "ws://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-java/chat";

   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
   }
   @Override
   public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       myService.getMyMethod(URL);
   }
}
```

My service class:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

     public void getMyMethod(String URL){
           WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
           WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
           stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
           StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
           stompClient.connect(URL, sessionHandler);
           new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); // Don't close immediately.
           }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to your `pom.xml` to create the correct jar?

Comment: Yes. Updated the post

Comment: if `mvn package` doesn't generate the jar, but starts the app, you probably have a test that blocks the proces.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please find the code updated above

Comment: Your service is blocking, hence preventing the test from finishing and thus maven cannot produce a jar.

Comment: https://paulsofts.com/how-to-package-spring-boot-application-to-jar/

Answer (score 6):

In order to run the jar with `java -jar` you should use `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This plugin will "bake" all the dependencies of the project into the JAR and add some "technical" code that will allow to run this JAR with `java -jar` (the exact details are kind of out of scope for this question)

If you add it into the build, and run `mvn package / mvn install` it will create in the `target` folder a big JAR next to the original jar (that will be renamed with suffix `.original`).

You can open it with WinRAR/WinZIP and make sure that all your classes are there and all the dependencies are in `BOOT-INF/lib` folder.

Then you can run the project with `java -jar`

Comment: I have the spring-boot-maven-plugin in pom.xml but jar not generated. Updated my post.

Comment: run `mvn clean package` - by default the "repackage" goal is bound to "package" phase in maven (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html)

Comment: mvn clean package also not working, my main class is using implements CommandLineRunner and starts invoking the method on build

Comment: try to generate the same project from https://start.spring.io/ and see the differences with your pom...

Answer (score 2):

1. In `pom.xml` add tag `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.
2. you can `build` the `maven project` using command `mvn package` or `maven install`. It will create the `.jar` file inside `target` folder.
3. run command from location where `.jar` is present - `java -jar jarName.jar`

Now you can access your `system`

Answer (score 2):

## Follow these steps

> **for eclipse/spring tool suite**

- right click on project name to get these options --> Click on run as `maven build`
  [image: right click on project name to get these options]
- Add Goal as package and click on Run button at bottom right corner
  [image: goal for package]
- jar file will be generated inside **target** folder of your project. You can locate this and then run `java -jar` command
  [image]

Comment: Hijacking an older question with an answer that won't solve a thing isn't the way forward. The test is still blocking running `mvn package` through the UI won't fix that.

Comment: It works, because when we do mvn build it generates jar for project. I am not getting what do you want to say exactly.

Comment: They have a test that is reading input from the command line. The `mvn package` never finish. They already know they need the `mvn package` reiterating that doesn't make it suddenly work (they also mention the exact same in the question that `mvn package` never finishes).

Comment: thanks for comment, I got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use tests . you can use this solution .
before
you must delete test folder after you must run mvn clean install command in your project folder . after you can add this code in pom.xml anywhere
  `<packaging>jar</packaging>`and run mvn package command . the jar file will create .